# Flask app running on apache resulting in 404 error

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm using mac os x and trying to get [the official flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/) to work with Apache, but when I attempt to open the site in localhost on my browser it results in a 404: `The requested URL / was not found on this server.` I followed [these directions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/) for configuring mod_wsgi for flask. I've run the app using the built in server with flask so I know the app itself works.

The following is the resulting error in the Apache error log

```
[negotiation:error] [pid 7563] [client ::1:50509] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /Library/WebServer/Documents/flaskr/flaskr.wsgi (None could be negotiated).
```

Here is what I have in my `flaskr.wsgi` file located in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/flaskr/flaskr.wsgi`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Library/WebServer/Documents/flaskr')

from flaskr import app as application
```

I have the following in my httpd.conf file

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName localhost

    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskr user=_www group=_www threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /Library/WebServer/Documents/flaskr/flaskr.wsgi

    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/flaskr>
        WSGIProcessGroup flaskr
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted # httpd 2.4 syntax as noted in the guide
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-darwin.so
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6
```

From terminal when I run `sudo apachectl -M` it displays `wsgi_module (shared)`. If I comment out the code in my httpd.conf file that I've listed above, the `wsgi_module` goes away from the enabled modules list, so unless there's something I'm not aware of mod_wsgi seems to be enabled successfully, but as I've mentioned I get a 404 message when trying to view the site.

**EDIT**

I don't think there's anything wrong with my Apache configuration. I tried [this tutorial](https://www.jakowicz.com/flask-apache-wsgi/) for getting flask up and running on Apache and it worked. I'll update once I figure out what I did wrong with the "flaskr" app.

**Edit - found the problem**

Turns out my `flaskr.wsgi` file was in the wrong directory. It was supposed to be in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/flaskr/flaskr/flaskr.wsgi`.

The official Flask tutorial I referenced uses the following directory structure

```
flaskr <----Initially put my `flaskr.wsgi` file in this directory
    init.py
    flaskr <----Changed to this directory and it worked
        flaskr.py
        flaskr.db
        flaskr.wsgi
```

Also changed the system path to `sys.path.append('/Library/WebServer/Documents/flaskr/flaskr')`

Comment: Please andd the solution as an answer. Then, you can accept it :)